# Combining static and random salts

Tags: php, mysql, crypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improve password hashing with a random salt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420722/improve-password-hashing-with-a-random-salt)

Is there a valid security reason to generate random salt, but then store it in the same DB as the password as well as a static salt?

For example:

```
$hashedPass = crypt($pass, $staticsalt.createRandomSalt());// just an example for sanity 
$user->setPass = hashedPass;
$hash->setSalt = createRandomSalt();//assuming same result...
```

I know the security community recommends using an exisitng column for the hash (like username), but i really don't see a point.
If the DB is hacked, the attacker would get usernames as well...
While if it's in a separate column/table , I can incorporate additional security measures.

Comment: After reading the proposed dupe, I concur. I was part-way through typing a comment to the affect of "salts don't need to be secret" :)

Comment: My idea was combining the static and random.
Also while it's generally true that salt doesn't need to be secret (PBKDF2). the concept is becoming less secure as CPU cycles get cheaper...

Answer (score 4):

If you're generating per-record salts, you **HAVE** to store the salt along with the hashed password. Otherwise you'll never be able to verify the pw, e.g.

register_user:

```
$salt = rand_salt();
$pw = 'foo';
$hashed = md5($salt . $pw);
```

login:

```
$pw = $_POST['password'];
$hashed = md5($pw);  // oops... no salt. can't hash the pw properly anymore.
```

If your server's been hacked, then it doesn't matter WHICH database the hash, salt, userna mes are spread across - they're going out the door.

But at least with the salt you've made the attacker's job more difficult, because now their script kiddy rainbow tables don't apply anymore. They had have a pregenerated hash for the usual passwords (`12345`, `password`, etc...), but not for `2d%@#41234xrs12345` or `89yusdf;hjlk2342sdf@@password`.

Comment: I want to share the security responsibility across multiple servers.
The attacker would need to:
1)Get into the web server to get the static salt
2)Get into the users database to get the hash
3)Get into the Hashing database/server to get the random salt

Comment: I also the question is not whether i need to store the dynamic salt.
that part is abvious.
It's more of an idea for the method of hashing/comparing hashes

Comment: what's the point? if your server gets hacked, then the attacker can duplicate your "get the hash from server Y" anyways. you'll have accomplished nothing, and increased your attack vulnerability to having multiple servers instead of just one.

Comment: Getting data stored hash is not the same as having the power to execute stuff.
for example:
The attacker can know my locally stored hash, know the password to the sql DB's but not be able to do anything (due the policy FW etc.)

Comment: you're not understanding. so you've got multiple servers. one storing the hash(salt+pw), one storing the salt, one storing the username, etc... you still have to fetch all of those to a single location to perform a login (say). since the data's fetchable, you've accomplished nothing. an attacker can still subvert your system to grab the salts + hashes + usernames. they may have to jump through a few hoops, e.g. maybe fetch the salts one at a time, but since they're still fetchable, they'll get fetched.

Comment: There's no perfect system.
however if you can hack a system (http://stupidserver.com/../hashes.txt) doesn't mean you got full root control over it...

Comment: @MarcB +1 for your point. i think that this is what -boruch is trying to say: it is easier to compromise three separate servers to READ data, than it is to compromise a single server to be able to EXECUTE (not sure if the point is correct, merely trying to gain the most from this convo). Since the data is spread on three servers it would pose a bigger challenge for an attacker