# Are we using Re hashing Password in C#

Tags: c#, hash

I am using Hashing and Salt to decrypt the password. that is the methods I am using:

```
  public string CreateSalt(int size)
    {
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var buff = new byte[size];
        rng.GetBytes(buff);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);

    }

    public string GenerateHash(string input, string salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt);
        SHA512Managed sha256 = new SHA512Managed();
        byte[] hash=  sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return ByteArrayToHexString(hash);
    }
```

After I hashed the password and save it to database, how I can rehash it? Or even if I need rehashing at all?
Users are going to create their password to login to the website. I haven't decide how forgot password is going to work, so maybe it is going to reset the password and send to them. Any thought, Idea around hashing?

Comment: Are you planning to 'rehash' it to reset the password? If so, you either allow the user to enter a new password and hash+salt that, or hash+salt a new generated password and replace the old one (or use a temp password column to allow old passwords to still be used)

Comment: FYI SHA512 is considered a poor choice for password hashing since it is too fast, there are some doubts on PBKDF schemes like bcrypt but it is likely to be a better choice. Here's a good q&a to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481160/is-bcrypt-a-good-hashing-algorithm-to-use-in-c-where-can-i-find-it

Comment: take a look at this.. there are also many other options out there you will need to do some researching and googling on your end as well http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/475262/UseplusBCryptplustoplusHashplusYourplusPasswords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store both the hashed password and password salt in the database. When the users log in, you get the input password, hashed it with the stored salt in database, then compare the result with the stored hashed password.

[image]

You're right about the forgot password. Just create a random password and send it to the users.