# C# Web.config using stronger like "Bcrypt" hashed password format in Form Authentication Credential

Tags: c#, forms, authentication, hash, passwords

For some reason, I have to store the username and password under web.config. I used to store like the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPNETAUTH" >
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user name="User1" password=" 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b" />
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Is there any more secure way like "Bcrypt" for hashing either than SHA1, MD5 but can still use the default form authentication credential tag?
I have tried to use 
https://www.zetetic.net/blog/2012/3/29/strong-password-hashing-for-aspnet.html
However, it need to use SQL service provider which cannot fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this implementation - https://bcrypt.codeplex.com/
I haven't used it myself, but I have been thinking about using something other than SHA for a upcoming project.

Edit: In fact there is a very good question and answer already on StackOverflow.
[Is BCrypt a good hashing algorithm to use in C#? Where can I find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481160/is-bcrypt-a-good-hashing-algorithm-to-use-in-c-where-can-i-find-it)

Comment: But after I import the dll can I change it to like following? or I have to write another class to handle this?<credentials passwordFormat="BCrypt">
      <user name="User1" password=" 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b" />
    </credentials>